# Selenium IDE - Upload file into field

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'm creating a testing suite to automate some parts of data input on my web application. I have a page where I can click on a button to upload a document to the application. It looks something like this:

[image: screenshot 1]

Once the Add New Attachment button is clicked, it opens the browser's file explorer to select a document to upload. I'm trying to replicate this within Selenium IDE.

Here is what it looks like as of now:

[image: screenshot 2]

However, this part seems to fail. Does anyone know how to achieve a similar process using Selenium IDE? I'm on Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 16):

If you get the

> {"code":-32000,"message":"Not allowed"}

on Chrome, follow the steps below:

Window > More Tools > Extensions > Selenium IDE > Details

Then turn on the 'Allow access to file URLs' option.

I was having the same problem and this worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

It is **possible** to upload the files using selenium IDE. It can be done as mentioned below.

```
|Command|Target|Value|

|type|target_location_path|location_of_the_file_in_your_system|
```

**Example:**

```
|type|id=ConsignmentCustomerInvoiceFilename|C:\Users\abc\Desktop\img1.jpg|
```

You can identify the "target_location_path" by manually uploading the file and then finding the xpath of the uploaded file in the web app.

Please refer below screenshot to get a better understanding.

[SeleniumIDE_uploadfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjlHW.png)

**You can add the system path to the IDE test by using the below code.**

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>Preferences.getString(TestSuite.TEST_SUITE_DIRECTORY_PREF);</td>
    <td>testSuiteFolder</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=QuestionUpload_file</td>
    <td>${testSuiteFolder}/resources/question_upload.csv</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Selenium IDE addon in Chrome says: 
type on id=files with value C:\\README.txt Failed:
{"code":-32000,"message":"Not allowed"}

Comment: See the first answer to fix your not allowed issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with files and folders starting with the letter "r" -> the path delimiter on windows "" in conjunction with the "r" resulted in "\r" which is interpreted as a carriage return - this led to false file names and the upload did not work.